# How to understand Galois Representations as an undergraduate?

Tags: soft-question, galois-theory, galois-representations

I am looking to doing my undergraduate thesis on Galois Representation Theory.

I am currently taking a class in Galois Theory and learning Algebraic Geometry independently.

Are there any resources that I can look at to get an idea of whether or not I am prepared to write a thesis on Galois Theory. Thank you.

Comment: First you have go deeper into abatract algebra